# jQuery: pagination with item per page from select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I'm creating a pagination using jquery and I want to allow the users to select the amount of results/items being shown on the page using a select dropdown menu.

my pagination works without the select option but when I involve the select option part. the pagination stops working and also the select option part never works.

I have created this jsfiddle to explain this issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/q5rgLwb8/5/

in the code above when I change the `itemperPage = Itemoption;` to `itemperPage = 2;` or `itemperPage = *ANY NUMBER*;` the pagination starts working again.

I did try to `alert();` the `Itemoption` once the select option is selected and it works fine and i get the value in the alert box but I don't understand why it doesn't work when I try to use the value like the way I explained in my code above.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Can you please try it?

```
var countries = [];
var per_page = 10;
function generate_pagination(per_page) {
    var pagination_links = countries.length / per_page;
    var pagination_length = Math.ceil(pagination_links);
    $('#pagination').html('');
    for (var i = 1; i <= pagination_length; i++) {
        $('#pagination').append('<a href="#" class="page">' + i + '</a>');
    }
}

function display_countries(start, end) {

    $('.new').html('');
    for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {

        if (i >= start && i < end) {
            $('.new').append('<tr><td>' + (i + 1) + ": " + countries[i] + '</td><td>Action</td></tr>');
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#displayvalues").change(function () {
        per_page = $(this).find("option:selected").val()
        var end = 1 * per_page;
        var start = 0;
        display_countries(start, end);
        generate_pagination(per_page);
    })

    $('body').on('click', '.page', function () {
        var page_no = $(this).html();
        var end = page_no * per_page;
        var start = end - per_page;
        display_countries(start, end);
        return false;
    })

    $.ajax({
        url: './countries.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { countries: true },
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            countries = data.countries;
            generate_pagination(per_page);
            display_countries(0, per_page);
        }
    });
});
```